# Display SQL table in PHP/HTML Table

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli, html-table

I am trying to get my SQL table to populate into an HTML table via PHP. However, I just get the table header created. What's wrong with the populating? Here's my code:

```
 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("server.com","username","password");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Orders");

echo "<table>";
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>orderNumber</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>customerName</th>
<th>salesRep</th>
<th>DatePicker</th>
<th>shipMethod</th>
<th>trackingNumber</th>
<th>Statuscheck</th>
<th>Edit</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['orderNumber'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Price'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['customerName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['salesRep'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['DatePicker'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['shipMethod'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['trackingNumber'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Statuscheck'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Edit'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

The 'Edit' is so i can have an edit hyperlink to use SQL UPDATE. It is not actually part of the SQL table in the database. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

OK, so here is the problem now, the edit page doesn't prepopulate the fields that have already been filled out, nor does the update button actually update the db. Here is the code for the edit page.

```
$query = "SELECT orderNumber, customerName, salesRep, DatePicker, shipMethod, trackingNumber, StatusCheck FROM Orders WHERE id = '$id'";
$result = @mysql_query($query);

mysql_fetch_object($result);
?>
<form name="update order" method="post" action="edit.php?a=edit&id=<? echo($ID) ?>&update=1">
  <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr> 
      <td width="50%">Order Number</td>
      <td><input name="orderNumber" type="text" id="orderNumber" value="<? echo($row->orderNumber) ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td>Customer Name</td>
      <td><input name="customerName" type="text" id="customerName" value="<? echo($row->customerName) ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td>Sales Rep</td>
      <td><input name="headline" type="text" id="headline" value="<? echo($row->headline) ?>"></td>
         <tr> 
      <td>Must Ship By</td>
      <td><input name="DatePicker" type="text" id="DatePicker" value="<? echo($row->DatePicker) ?>"></td>
         <tr> 
      <td>Shipping Method</td>
      <td><input name="shipMethod" type="text" id="shipMethod" value="<? echo($row->shipMethod) ?>"></td>
         <tr> 
      <td>Tracking Number</td>
      <td><input name="trackingNumber" type="text" id="trackingNumber" value="<? echo($row->trackingNumber) ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td>Status</td>
      <td><input name="StatusCheck" type="radio" name="status" value="PROCESSING"> PROCESSING<br><input name="StatusCheck" type="radio" name="status" value="PROCESSING"> PICKED<br><input name="StatusCheck" type="radio" name="status" value="PROCESSING" value="<? echo($row->StatusCheck) ?>"> SHIPPED<br>  value="<? echo($row->StatusCheck) ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td colspan="2"><div align="center">
          <input name="hiddenField" type="hidden" value="update">
          <input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Update">
        </div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
<?php

?>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever specified the database name.

Comment: You need to select db `$db_selected = mysqli_select_db('db_name', $con);`

Comment: You need to set DB name. Also it is better to check $result after "$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Orders");" (now it looks like you just ignore error status)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$result` variable is empty, test it out.
The reason why is because you did not set up any database name where you can get information from.
Paste this:

```
mysqli_select_db($con, 'your_database_name');
```

after

```
$con=mysqli_connect("server.com","username","password");
```

and it should be okay (of course if you have any records there).

Comment: Or `$con=mysqli_connect("server.com","username","password","dbname");`

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, I can't believe I forgot to select the database. (Sorry) Any tips on creating the Edit hyperlink to a page for UPDATE? I'm really not sure on how to do it, even if it just gives me access to type directly into the fields to UPDATE. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3528394 mark my answer as a solution if it works for you. This is a good article about how you can create an "edit" page: http://www.dmxzone.com/go/4114/creating-a-news-module-using-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Marked as solution. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @user3528394 you are welcome, let me know if you need any additional info

Comment: @PavelDenisevich I looked over that article you sent me, however when I try to use the edit page to update, none of the previously filled out fields are prefilled and the update button does nothing, I have attached the code to my original post, thank you again so much for all your help.

Answer (score -1):

Your code aboove is kindof lengthy so, i'm going to take a smaller example.
lets assume you have a record of id and name. to create the edit/update links change the while loop to some thing similar to the following

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href='editform.php?id=" . $row['ID'] . "'>Edit</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

this will append an edit link to all the rows. and create the editform.php as follows:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST["ID"])&&isset($_POST["name"])){
        //this is if the user is applying the edit
        $ID = $_POST["ID"];
        $name = $_POST["name"];

        //go ahead and save this detail on your db.....
    }else if(isset($_POST["ID"])){
        //this is if the user is just entering the editform from the table
        $ID = $_POST["ID"];
        $name = ;//get it from the data base with a query something like SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $id;
    }else{
        //in case the user access this page directly
        $ID = "";
        $name = "";
    }

?>

<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="ID" value="<?php echo $ID?>"/>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name?>"/>    
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

you can handle  the update on the same page too, and i recommend that. Also you can create an edit form using JavaScript but comes with some complexity.