# Echo variables from a SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to make a select query and output this information into a html tags, however it keep converting the php code to this:

```
<!--? echo $news_text; ?-->
```

What am i doing wrong? and why isnt it returning error instead of converting it to above?

code

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','pass','db');
$theId = $_GET['id'];
<?

$all_news = $con->prepare("SELECT 
n.id, 
n.title, 
n.url, 
n.image_url, 
n.date, 
n.news_text, 
w.url as website_url, 
w.image as website_image 
from news n
join website w on w.id = n.website_id
where  n.id = ? limit 1"); 
$all_news->bind_param("i", $theId);
$all_news->execute();
$all_news->bind_result($id, $title, $url, $image_url, $date, $news_text,     $url, $referer_img);
$all_news->fetch();

  ?>

<div class='main_image' style='background-image:url(<?php echo $image_url; ?>)' title=''></div>
   <p class="title">
    <? echo $title; ?>
  </p>
   <img class="referer" src="<?php echo $referer_img ?>" alt="">
   <div class="text_div">
        <p>
          <? echo $news_text; ?>
        </p>
   </div>
```

Comment: The part of the code where you try to echo the value is missing...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039781/display-sql-table-in-php-html-table

Comment: works fine when i put `echo $news_text;` right below the `$all_news->fetch();`, but not in the `<p>` tag??

Comment: You never use `$all_news`. you define it, but never actually USE it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the part of the code where you echo the information out at contained in `'<?php ... ?>'`

EDIT
I can't respond to other posts yet (need 50 rep) but the reason you can't place the echo below the `<p>` as opposed to the `$all_news->fetch();` tag is because it is below the `?>` tag.  Just place it wherever you want but surround it in `<?php echo $news_text; ?>` and done.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the php syntax is not correct. 
You can use the following:

```
<?php echo $variable ?>
```

This will echo out the variable. Alternative you could use the following syntax

```
<?= $variable ?>
```